# Comparison of Javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, comparison

After the suggestion to use a library for [my ajax needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486/what-more-is-needed-for-ajax-than-this-function) I am going to use one, the problem is that there are so many and I've no idea how to even begin telling them apart.

Thus, can anybody 
A) Give a rundown of the differences or 
B) Point me (and others like me) somewhere that has such a list. 

Failing that plan C is to go with whichever gets mentioned the most here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer B:

[**Comparison of JavaScript frameworks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)

---

**EDIT:** Although everyone and their mom is apparently riding the [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) bandwagon (I use [**MochiKit**](http://www.mochikit.com)), there are many libraries which provide the same functionality - the problem set which most libraries solve (async client-server communication, DOM manipulation, etc.) is the same, and there are few that don't have what you will need to get the job done.

The important thing to determine for yourself is whether or not a library will fit your particular style and sensibilities. Wide-spread ignorance about how [**JavaScript**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), the language, actually works, coupled with the negative press resulting thereby, coupled with the now-immense popularity of jQuery leads most people down that road. Thankfully, it isn't a bad road to be on as there are a lot of travellers to keep you company when the abstractions leak and you need help. You probably can't go wrong choosing jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery, easy to learn, easy to use, small footprint, active plugin developer community.  Can't go wrong with jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth [jQuery's](http://jquery.com/) website redesign launched this morning (Friday August 29, 2008).  Good fun fact.  And of course +1 to its mention.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)?

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow uses jquery I think, and I hear that jquery is all the rage

Answer (score 3):

I have to put in another vote for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is dead-simple to use and makes your javascript much cleaner.

As an example, if you want to add an onclick event to all the divs inside an element with id "clickdivs", you just do this:

```
function clickedme(event) {
  alert('Someone clicked me!');
}
$('#clickdivs div').click(clickedme);
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="clickdivs">
  <div>Click Here</div>
  <div>And Here</div>
  <p>Not here</p>
  <div>Click Here Too</div>
</div>
```

Viola!

Answer (score 3):

Related thread here, with some good contributions:

[What JavaScript library would you choose for a new project and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why)

Answer (score 2):

We are starting to use jQuery where I work. I'm not big on JavaScript, but everyone else likes it a lot. I don't know if that helps at all...

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) + [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/).

They have good API documentation and work great for me!  The biggest benefits are:

- Cleans up messy javascript code
- Cross browser compatibility
- Simplifies AJAX handling
- Smooth UI effects

Answer (score 1):

I suggest restricting yourself to a library which can be pulled from a free CDN such as  [Google's AJAX CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) or [Microsoft's AJAX CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn).  Availability on a CDN indicates a certain minimum level of popularity and using one will allow you to load your web pages faster.  jQuery is my preferred library and is available on both the Google and MS CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is the best framework I have seen out there... it is embracing modern methods of coding such as simple, clean and fast code.

Go for jQuery...