# JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript

Its kinda difficult to get into Web development. I've been working on winforms for the last 5 years. So i'm struggling to switch from the one to the other. Some time ago, I worked with JavaScript, but no-a-days there are tons of JavaScript libraries - JQuery, JSON, MooTools...

**My Question:**

Perhaps this is a stupid question. What are the diff. between all there libraries? Can I work with only one of them? If i'm using JQuery, will I need JSON? Basically, is there a right tool for certain jobs?

Thanks

Comment: JSON is not a library - it is a format which can for example be used as an alternative for XML for communicating between your AJAX webapp and the server. See http://json.org/

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050/comparison-of-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 2):

You can use any library independently.

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a ***lightweight data-interchange format***.

and jQuery supports some builtin methods for dealing with JSON data.

The main advantage ( which I think ) of using jQuery is that it has a large user base and has plenty of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use jQuery but rather oddly, to my mind, it does not have good JSON support - lacking a stringify function for example.  However you can fill the gap at [JSON.org](http://json.org/js.html).

Whichever library you end up using it is a good idea to pull it from a free CDN such as  [Google's AJAX CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) or [Microsoft's AJAX CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want from a JavaScript framework/library as to which one is best for you. Although there are plenty of similarities between them, I think they embrace different philosophies, and it really depends on which philosophy fits you best as to which one you should go with.

I'd definitely recommend reading [jQuery and MooTools](http://jqueryvsmootools.com/), an article by Aaron Newton (a MooTools developer) discussing the differences between these two frameworks and why he prefers MooTools.

Also, as others have noted, JSON isn't a library—it's a data format. [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) *is* a library, but only for encoding/decoding the JSON format. Most JavaScript libraries like jQuery, MooTools, etc. contain their own JSON encoding/decoding functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the library you like, but jQuery seems to be more popular than others and is my personal favorite too. Check out the [why does everyone like jquery more than other libraries question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototype-script-aclo-us-or-mootools-or-w).

As the others pointed out, JSON is not a library.